# How to capture the exit code of a shell script in a perl script?

Tags: perl, shell

i want to pop up an alert box using perl script. I am using  `exit 0`  to terminate the shell script successfully and  `exit 1`  to terminate the shell script when an error occurs. I want to capture this exit code in the perl script. And depending on the value 0 or 1, I want to pop up an alert box with success or failure message respectively.

Answer (score 10):

You can check the exit code of another process with the child error variable [`$?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24?). For example:

```
system("perl foo.pl");
my $exit_val = $? >> 8;   # now contains the exit value of the perl script
```

Read the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24?) for more info.

Comment: i used your method, but its giving 127. but i am using exit 0 in my shell script. so, i need a 0 instead of 127.

Comment: @Rahul : `$? & 127` will give you what you want, as explained in the linked documentation.

Comment: ok i got. now how can i pop up a alert box in the perl script or using javascript inside perl.

Answer (score 7):

In case of exit 0:- shell script returns 0 to perl script $? variable

but for exit 1 case:-it return 256 so needed to be shifted by 8 
therefore try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "pelr";
system("./shell.sh");
$p=$?>>8;
print $p;
```

NOTE- in shell script just put exit 0 and run and then exit 1. and see the o/p

Just a note, when using system in perl, it returns the exit code multiplied by 256. So, if a command returns 1, system("command") will return 256. So, to get the real return value, divide by 256.